# geospatial query does not work on another pc

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I need to make some geospatial queries on a **mongodb** collection. I created a **2dsphere index on a GeoJSON point object**. The object is this:

```
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -122.419416, 37.77493 ] } }
```

I added the index using

```
db.Venue.ensureIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})
```

It workes perfectly well on my mac. But then I moved to a Ubuntu PC and re-created the database and the indexes. **But on Ubuntu geospatial queries do not work.** MongoDB says

```
{ errmsg: 'no geo index :(', ok: 0 }
```

On my mac, db.Venue.getIndexes returns :

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "syftdb.Venue",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
             "loc" : "2dsphere"
         },
        "ns" : "syftdb.Venue",
        "name" : "loc_2dsphere"
    }
]
```

But on the Ubuntu PC db.Venue.getIndexes() returns a different object:

```
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "syftdb.Venue",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "loc" : "2dsphere"
    },
    "ns" : "syftdb.Venue",
    "name" : "loc_"
}
]
```

You see the name field is different. Is this the problem? Do the name fields have to be same?

Mongo version:
Mac: 2.0.6 64bits
Ubuntu: 2.4.4 64bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2dsphere indexes are not available in mongodb versions earlier than **2.4**

How stupid of me! I asked a really silly question without looking up first!